# How to determine the association between a VB6 app and an exe instanced with CreateObject()

Tags: vb6, dcom, createobject

We need to figure out how a service can peek at a running VB6 app and/or its DCOM spawned exe and figure out which VB6 app goes with which DCOM exe. The VB6 app and the spawned exe are both on the same server.

We have a VB6 app that spawns an instance of Bartender (from Seagull Scientific) by way of a CreateObject() call. On a given server, we may have ten or twenty instances of our app, each represents a handheld RF gun client in a warehouse. 95% or more of these VB6 apps will have their own Bartender.

Due to circumstances beyond our control, randomly, one of our VB6 instances will be killed, just as if you killed it using Task Manager. This leaves it's Bartender still alive and consuming resources. After fifty or so have been killed over the course of a few hours or days, these orphaned Bartenders become enough of a resource hog to bring the server to its knees.

We are trying to develop a watcher service to detect which of the Bartenders are still connected, so this new service can kill the orphaned Bartenders. We are trying to accomplish this without changing our VB6 app, but we will modify our app if we have to.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [routine](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=73), aptly named Who's Your Daddy, might be of use to you. It figures out who spawned the process.  It probably won't solve your entire problem, but it's a start.

Comment: I have to check this out. I know the API in your code won't help me per se(multiple Bartenders would all report the same Path to our app), but this is a corner of the Win32API's I had not looked into yet. If this does what you indicate, then a cousin of this API might be what I am looking for!

Comment: No Joy so far! The API used in "Who's Your Daddy" would work for a ActiveX DLL, but does NOT work for an Active X EXE, like Bartender!

Comment: @arg342 There must be an API that handles a case like yours because if you run up Process Explorer, it shows relationships between parent and child.

Comment: Begging to differ, but in this case that is NOT TRUE. Each instance of our app is listed under Explorer. The spawned EXE's are NOT listed there, but rather under the svchost running the DCOM Service. Using Process Explorer, you can not see the association, unless there is something buried in the Handles of either our App or the Bartender that I have not yet noticed...

Comment: @arg342, I don't have vb6 handy on the weekend, but I'll check what happens when VB spawns Excel during the week.I  thought it would appear under the VB6 process, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be hard, if not impossible, to do. Out-of-process COM components (i.e. ActiveX EXE's) are always started by the COM Service Control Manager, not by the process that called **CreateObject**. This is why the parent process for the ActiveX EXE is **svchost.exe**.

Therefore, there is no direct parent-child relationship between the process that calls **CreateObject** and the process that gets created. Only the remote procedure call (RPC) layer that actually passes method calls back and forth between the two processes knows the identities of the processes involved, but the RPC mechanism is specifically designed to be transparent to the COM subsystem, and there isn't an easy way to get access to this information that I know of.

However, there is a pretty hackish way to handle the orphaned process problem if you are willing to change the VB6 application:

1. Have your monitor service periodically terminate *all* running Bartender EXE's (once a day or however often is necessary to prevent the server from slowing down too much).
2. Write a wrapper DLL for the Bartender functionality, and have your VB6 class use this wrapper library instead of directly instantiating raw Bartender objects. This library would contain a wrapper class that creates a Bartender object, and that has methods that delegate to this object. Each wrapper method should catch error 462 ("The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"), recreate the Bartender object if this occurs, and then retry the method.

For example (I haven't actually looked at the Bartender documentation, so this is just demonstrating the idea):

```
'BartenderWrapper.cls

Private m_bartender As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_bartender = CreateObject("Bartender.Application")    
End Sub

Public Sub PrintLabel(Byval sLabelData As String)

    On Error Goto ErrorHandler

    m_bartender.PrintLabel sLabelData

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    If IsRpcError(Err) Then
       Set m_bartender = CreateObject("Bartender.Application")
       Resume
    End If

    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description

End Sub

Private Function IsRpcError(Byval e As ErrObject) As Boolean
    IsRpcError = (e.Number = 462)
End Function
```

The idea here is that since you can't reliably determine which Bartender processes are still connected to an instance of your VB6 application, you can kill all of the running Bartender processes periodically, and your application will still be able to run properly (in most cases), because if you kill a Bartender EXE that was being used by a running instance of your VB6 application, your application will create a new Bartender instance and continue running normally.

This solution definitely isn't fool-proof, and may be hard to implement if you are using a lot of methods or the Bartender instance you create has important internal state that could be lost when creating a new instance.

When it comes down to it, there isn't a clean way to detect orphaned ActiveX EXE's if you don't control all of the applications that are involved (one common solution when you *do* control the ActiveX EXE is to have the ActiveX EXE raise an event with a *ByRef* parameter every second or so, and have it shut itself down if the client doesn't change the value of the parameter).

Comment: Interesting comments. I thank you for them. Since we are really trying to avoid changing our app or Bartender, I am going to keep looking at APIs to see if there is any relief there. Otherwise I have to admit there is great merit in the two solutions you suggest a)kill all the Bartenders and re-create as needed or b) the public counter method. I remember the public counter method on a system in the late 1970's where two CPU's watched each other to see if it's mate needed a reboot. Talk about a flashback!

Comment: @arg342: Another way to implement the "public counter" method is to write an ActiveX EXE with a single public _GlobalMultiUse_ class defined, that has a _CreateBartender_ method for example. This method could do the following: (a) Snapshot all the processes on the system (b) call **CreateObject** to create a Bartender object (c) snapshot the processes again (d) compare both snapshots looking for a new Bartender process, and retrieve it's process ID (e) return the object and the Bartender process ID to the client. Your VB6 app would reference this EXE and use it to get Bartender objects.

Comment: Since this ActiveX is multi-use, only one instance will ever be loaded on the machine, and COM will synchronize all calls to the _CreateBartender_ method, so no risk of a new Bartender process appearing between taking the snapshots. Each client can then write its own process ID and the process ID returned from the _CreateBartender_ method to a file somewhere (overwriting existing entries). The monitor script will periodically read this file, and kill only those Bartender processes whose corresponding VB6 process doesn't exist anymore, and also remove the process IDs from the file.

Comment: So, for example: instead of `Set obj = CreateObject("Bartender.Application")`, your app could do `Set obj = BartenderProxy.CreateBartender(bartenderProcId_Out)`, then immediately write `bartenderProcId_Out` and its own process ID (which you can get with a call to **GetCurrentProcessId**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a file. Your monitor service just reads this file line by line: if the Bartender process ID refers to a running process, but the corresponding app process ID is not running, kill the Bartender process, and remove the line from the file.

Answer (score 0):

What we have decided to do is to have the client write a hint file each time the Client creates a Bartender. The client writes a tiny XML file in a common folder that says an XML equivalent of "I am PID number n. Between time x and time y, I created a Bartender." The times x and y are timestamps obtained immediately before and after the CreateObject call. We will have a monitor service that watches for new Clients, new Bartenders and hint files. By watching all these, we think we can create small groups or associations of clients and their associated bartenders. In any given group, when all the clients go away, any remaining Bartenders that were in that group can be KILLED!