# How to retrieve PID(Process ID) of a com application created by net assembly

Tags: asp.net, com

I am calling third party com object from an ASP.NET that invoke an executable  as follows

b = new myBw.Baan4Class();

At any given time there could be muliple instances invoked by ASP processes.
How can I get the PID of b so that I can 'Kill' it without disturbing(killing) others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more details about the COM object you are using I don't think there's any great way to associate the exe it launches and the object you are creating.

With that said you could delegate the responsibility of creating these objects to a centralized location (WCF service running in SingleInstance mode maybe) that can associate the object created to the exe by instantiating a new object and waiting for the exe to be launched.  When the exe has been launched it can then associate the object it created with the exe launched.  You could use [**WMI**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to detect when a new exe has been launched.

It's going to be pretty much impossible to do this in asp.net since multiple users could be instantiating these objects at the same time.  You would be running into race conditions if you tried to do this here.

Here is a similar question:  [How to determine the association between a VB6 app and an exe instanced with CreateObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430795/how-to-determine-the-association-between-a-vb6-app-and-an-exe-instanced-with-crea)